# CNAME pointing to an ec2 instance public host

Tags: amazon-ec2, cname

Is it a good practice to create CNAME of my domain to point to ec2 instances ?

For example, if my own the domain mydomain.com and I have this ec2 instance whith a public host : ec2-aa-bb-cc-dd.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Can I create a CNAME prod-database.mydomain.com to ec2-aa-bb-cc-dd.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com and use that subdomain instead of the ec2 public host ?

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice, that way you don't have to remember odd dns names when configuring future applications and architectures.